# How to evaluate $\int \sin(x)\arcsin(x)dx$

Tags: integration

I need to evaluate following integral

$$\int \sin(x)\arcsin(x) \ dx$$

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe write the second term as $\arcsin{x}$ to avoid confusion :)

Comment: I would be surprised is this integral has a closed form in terms of standard functions.

Comment: This integral seems unsolvable

Comment: One problem might be that $\sin:\mathbb{R}\mapsto [-1,1]$ whereas $\arcsin:[-1,1]\mapsto [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: i tried $t = \sin x,$  needed the $\int \sin(\sin t) \, dt$  and that is as hard to find as the original one.

Answer (score 4):

I shall not repeat that there is probably no closed form for the integral. But Taylor expansion could help; using the standard formulas for $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$, one can obtain for the product $$\sin(x)\arcsin(x)=x^2+\frac{x^6}{18}+\frac{x^8}{30}+\frac{2669 x^{10}}{113400}+\frac{601
   x^{12}}{34020}+\frac{726587 x^{14}}{52390800}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$$ and, integrating, $$\int\sin(x)\arcsin(x)\, dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^7}{126}+\frac{x^9}{270}+\frac{2669 x^{11}}{1247400}+\frac{601
   x^{13}}{442260}+\frac{726587 x^{15}}{785862000}+O\left(x^{17}\right)$$ which, taking into account Demosthene's remark about the maximum range for integration, will converge quite rapidly.

Comment: claude, where do you get these series so fast?

Comment: @abel. Did you notice my age ? For all that time, I am in love with Taylor series and making products of so simple expression is just a piece of my best cakes. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Sir, I like that comment. Very positive

Comment: i have noticed your age. i hope when i get there i will still be doing and enjoying math as much as you do now and will do for a long time.

Comment: @abel. Thank you ! I am sure you will do even much more. Good luck !

Answer (score 4):

The integrand does [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) possess an [elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) anti-derivative. However, as far as definite integrals are concerned, we have the following results in terms of the special [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions:

> $$\begin{align}
> &\int_0^1\sin x\cdot\arcsin x~dx~=~\frac\pi2~\Big[J_0(1)-\cos(1)\Big],
> \\
> &\int_0^1\sin x\cdot\arccos x~dx~=~\frac\pi2~\Big[1-J_0(1)\Big],
> \\
> &\int_0^1\cos x\cdot\arcsin x~dx~=~\frac\pi2~\Big[\sin(1)-H_0(1)\Big],
> \\
> &\int_0^1\cos x\cdot\arccos x~dx~=~\frac\pi2~H_0(1).
> \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, there seems to be "no closed form in terms of standard functions" (to quote `Simon S`). Also, you have to be careful that the domains of the two functions are not the same: $\sin(x)$ takes values from $\mathbb{R}$, but the domain of $\arcsin(x)$ is restricted to $[-1,1]$.

However, one can perform numerical integration without too much difficulties. In particular, integrating on the full (real) range of $\arcsin(x)$ yields the interesting result:

$$\int_{-1}^1\sin(x)\arcsin(x)\ dx\simeq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-5.7\times 10^{-4}$$